# When I open dropdown menu, it pushes all the rest of the conten of the page down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a pure css/html dropdown menu. The problem is, when I click on it, it pushes all the rest of the content down.
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

[Image of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6bhK.png)

This is the project

https://github.com/amarantak/css-only-select-radio-checkbox_edited

```css
.menu-select {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  /* box-shadow: 0px 1em 2em -1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */
}

.menu-select:not(:hover)>i.toggle.icon-arrow-down {
  display: block !important;
}

.menu-select:not(:hover)>i.toggle.icon-arrow-up {
  display: none !important;
}

.menu-select:not(:hover) label.option>input:not(:checked)~span.title {
  display: none !important;
}

.menu-select>i.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  right: 1.5em;
  top: 1.6em;
  color: #ccc;
}

.menu-select .title,
.menu-select .placeholder {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-select>input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-select>input:checked~i.toggle.icon-arrow-down {
  display: none;
}

.menu-select>input:checked~i.toggle.icon-arrow-up {
  display: block;
}

.menu-select>input:checked div.options label.option .title {
  display: none !important;
}

.menu-select>input:not(:checked) {
  z-index: 4;
}

.menu-select>input:not(:checked)~label.option>span.title {
  display: none;
}

.menu-select>input:not(:checked)~i.toggle.icon-arrow-up {
  display: none;
}

.menu-select>input:not(:checked)~i.toggle.icon-arrow-down {
  display: block;
}

.menu-select>input:disabled {
  cursor: no-drop;
}

.menu-select>span.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #999;
  border-top: 0px;
}

.menu-select label.option {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.menu-select label.option span.title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
}

.menu-select label.option span.title i.icon {
  padding-right: 8px;
  color: #92a8d1;
}

.menu-select label.option span.title:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.menu-select label.option input {
  display: none;
}

.menu-select label.option input:checked~span.title {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: min-content;
}

.menu-select label.option input:disabled~span.title {
  background: #f9f9f9 !important;
  color: #aaa;
}

.menu-select label.option input:disabled~span.title:hover {
  color: #aaa;
  background: none;
  cursor: no-drop;
}


/* Styling of the icons */

.status-circle-on {
  /* width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #4bb543;
         border: 1px solid white;
         */
  color: #4bb543;
}

.status-circle-paused {
  /* width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        background-color: #f0ad4e; 
        border-radius: 50%;
         border: 1px solid white;
        */
  color: #f0ad4e;
}

.status-circle-off {
  /* width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        background-color: #d9534f;
         border-radius: 50%; 
        border: 1px solid white;*/
  color: #d9534f;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="menu-select animated">
    <!-- You can toggle select (disabled) -->
    <input type="radio" name="option" />
    <i class="toggle icon icon-arrow-down"></i>
    <i class="toggle icon icon-arrow-up"></i>
    <span class="placeholder">Change status...</span>

    <label class="option">
      <input type="radio" name="option" />
      <span class="title animated fadeIn">
        <i class="fas fa-circle status-circle-on fa-lg"></i>
        online
      </span>
    </label>

    <label class="option">
      <input type="radio" name="option" />
      <span class="title animated fadeIn">
        <i class="fas fa-circle status-circle-paused fa-lg"></i>
        paused
      </span>
    </label>
    
    <label class="option">
      <input type="radio" name="option" />
      <span class="title animated fadeIn">
        <i class="fas fa-circle status-circle-off fa-lg"></i>
        offline</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>

<div>
  <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

I understand it has something to do with the position absolute/relative and the z-index but the css is a bit complex I tried things but it didn't work.

Comment: You would need to add position absolute on label, with class option, I tried to create demo for that, but your CSS is complex, so give it a try, if it does not help, I can give more time and can provide working solution

Comment: I just tried that, but when I click on it, the submenu doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very crude solution to what I think you want to get done.

We're going to add two classes to get the functionality I think you want. First of all, the drop down has to stay at the top and also be centered. So we are going to give the outermost parent of the drop-down which is the `form` element the class `positioned`. This will set it's position to absolute, and make it a flex item with width 100%, and justify all its children i.e the drop-down content to the center.

Now we need to deal with the `<h1>` tag. Because we made the drop-down an absolute position, it no longer forces elements under it to change position. So to make the `<h1>` tag visible, we can simply lower its position on the screen by an arbitrary amount of pixels, ex: 100px;

```css
.positioned { position:absolute; display: flex; justify-content: center; width: 100%;}

.down {position: relative; top: 100px;}


.menu-select {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  /* box-shadow: 0px 1em 2em -1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */
}

.menu-select:not(:hover)>i.toggle.icon-arrow-down {
  display: block !important;
}

.menu-select:not(:hover)>i.toggle.icon-arrow-up {
  display: none !important;
}

.menu-select:not(:hover) label.option>input:not(:checked)~span.title {
  display: none !important;
}

.menu-select>i.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  right: 1.5em;
  top: 1.6em;
  color: #ccc;
}

.menu-select .title,
.menu-select .placeholder {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-select>input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-select>input:checked~i.toggle.icon-arrow-down {
  display: none;
}

.menu-select>input:checked~i.toggle.icon-arrow-up {
  display: block;
}

.menu-select>input:checked div.options label.option .title {
  display: none !important;
}

.menu-select>input:not(:checked) {
  z-index: 4;
}

.menu-select>input:not(:checked)~label.option>span.title {
  display: none;
}

.menu-select>input:not(:checked)~i.toggle.icon-arrow-up {
  display: none;
}

.menu-select>input:not(:checked)~i.toggle.icon-arrow-down {
  display: block;
}

.menu-select>input:disabled {
  cursor: no-drop;
}

.menu-select>span.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #999;
  border-top: 0px;
}

.menu-select label.option {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.menu-select label.option span.title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
}

.menu-select label.option span.title i.icon {
  padding-right: 8px;
  color: #92a8d1;
}

.menu-select label.option span.title:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.menu-select label.option input {
  display: none;
}

.menu-select label.option input:checked~span.title {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: min-content;
}

.menu-select label.option input:disabled~span.title {
  background: #f9f9f9 !important;
  color: #aaa;
}

.menu-select label.option input:disabled~span.title:hover {
  color: #aaa;
  background: none;
  cursor: no-drop;
}


/* Styling of the icons */

.status-circle-on {
  /* width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #4bb543;
         border: 1px solid white;
         */
  color: #4bb543;
}

.status-circle-paused {
  /* width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        background-color: #f0ad4e; 
        border-radius: 50%;
         border: 1px solid white;
        */
  color: #f0ad4e;
}

.status-circle-off {
  /* width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        background-color: #d9534f;
         border-radius: 50%; 
        border: 1px solid white;*/
  color: #d9534f;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="positioned">
  <div class="menu-select animated">
    <!-- You can toggle select (disabled) -->
    <input type="radio" name="option" />
    <i class="toggle icon icon-arrow-down"></i>
    <i class="toggle icon icon-arrow-up"></i>
    <span class="placeholder">Change status...</span>

    <label class="option">
      <input type="radio" name="option" />
      <span class="title animated fadeIn">
        <i class="fas fa-circle status-circle-on fa-lg"></i>
        online
      </span>
    </label>

    <label class="option">
      <input type="radio" name="option" />
      <span class="title animated fadeIn">
        <i class="fas fa-circle status-circle-paused fa-lg"></i>
        paused
      </span>
    </label>
    
    <label class="option">
      <input type="radio" name="option" />
      <span class="title animated fadeIn">
        <i class="fas fa-circle status-circle-off fa-lg"></i>
        offline</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="down">
  <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Salad, it works. The thing is I have to add the class "down" to all the other sections down the page to avoid stack on top of each other right? And since this dropdown is goin to be in a navbar I will have to do the same for all the pages?

Comment: What you can do is have two outer most components, a header, and then a body with a 100px offset. Then you can put all your content inside the body. As done in this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp).

Comment: Thank you Salad. The solution was to wrap everything in a new div (.holder) and give it the class of relative, and then, the class of absolute to it's first child (menu-select-animated). I added the fixed code down here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head>
<style>


       body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: #999;
}
.holder {

min-height: 150px;
position:relative;
}
.menu-select {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* height: 100%; */
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  /* box-shadow: 0px 1em 2em -1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); */
}
.menu-select:not(:hover) > i.toggle.icon-arrow-down {
  display: block !important;
}
.menu-select:not(:hover) > i.toggle.icon-arrow-up {
  display: none !important;
}
.menu-select:not(:hover) label.option > input:not(:checked) ~ span.title {
  display: none !important;
}
.menu-select > i.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  right: 1.5em;
  top: 1.6em;
  color: #ccc;
}

.menu-select .title, .menu-select .placeholder {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-select > input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-select > input:checked ~ i.toggle.icon-arrow-down {
  display: none;
}
.menu-select > input:checked ~ i.toggle.icon-arrow-up {
  display: block;
}
.menu-select > input:checked div.options label.option .title {
  display: none !important;
}
.menu-select > input:not(:checked) {
  z-index: 4;
}
.menu-select > input:not(:checked) ~ label.option > span.title {
  display: none;
}
.menu-select > input:not(:checked) ~ i.toggle.icon-arrow-up {
  display: none;
}
.menu-select > input:not(:checked) ~ i.toggle.icon-arrow-down {
  display: block;
}
.menu-select > input:disabled {
  cursor: no-drop;
}

.menu-select > span.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #999;
  border-top: 0px;
}
.menu-select label.option {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.menu-select label.option span.title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
}
.menu-select label.option span.title i.icon {
  padding-right: 8px;
  color: #92a8d1;
}
.menu-select label.option span.title:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.menu-select label.option input {
  display: none;
}
.menu-select label.option input:checked ~ span.title {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: min-content;
}
.menu-select label.option input:disabled ~ span.title {
  background: #f9f9f9 !important;
  color: #aaa;
}
.menu-select label.option input:disabled ~ span.title:hover {
  color: #aaa;
  background: none;
  cursor: no-drop;
}

  /* Styling of the icons */

  .status-circle-on
    {
         color: #4bb543;
    }
    .status-circle-paused
    {
        color:#f0ad4e;
    }
    .status-circle-off
    {
      
        color:#d9534f;

    }
    </head>
</style>

<form action="">
          <div class="holder">
            <div class="menu-select animated">
              <input type="radio" name="option" />
              <i class="toggle icon icon-arrow-down"></i>
              <i class="toggle icon icon-arrow-up"></i>
              <span class="placeholder">Change status...</span>
    
              <label class="option">
                <input type="radio" name="option" />
                <span class="title animated fadeIn">
               <i class="fas fa-circle status-circle-on fa-lg"></i>online</span>
              </label>
    
              <label class="option">
                <input type="radio" name="option" />
                <span class="title animated fadeIn">
<i class="fas fa-circle status-circle-paused fa-lg"></i>
                  paused</span
                >
              </label>
              <label class="option">
                <input type="radio" name="option" />
                <span class="title animated fadeIn">
                <i class="fas fa-circle status-circle-off fa-lg"></i>   offline</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="section p-5 bg-light text-dark">
          <h1>Content 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="section p-5 bg-dark text-light">
          <h1>Content 2</h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).